# Magento editing files with javascript or html

Tags: javascript, php, html, magento

I was looking trough some files of Magento and I noticed that it's all written in PHP so I started to wonder if it's possible to edit those codes with JavaScript or HTML, if yes just certain files or every file?
The answers I am looking for are simply: Yes, all files. Yes, certain files and these are (file names and directory) or simple a No.
Thanks in advance

Comment: but why are you asking these silly questions here?? There are lot of sites available for these. Go through those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files under `app->code(all with .php extension)` You can write html in those within quotes like

```
' html here '
```

Files under `app->design (all with .phtml extension)`. This is where you should write your `js/html` stuff.

`But Magento made these files(.phtml) so that you can write php codes as well inside this.`